# Windows server 2012 : Access forbidden for xampp project

Tags: php, xampp, windows-server-2012

Checked almost stackoverflow answers but getting same error, using windows server 2012 installed XAMPP( Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2o PHP/5.6.36 ).

xampp does not access any project from htdocs other than xampp dashboard.

Error :

[image]

httpd-vhost.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite"
    ServerName local.yourdomain.com
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite">
        Require all granted 
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

hosts :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       local.yourdomain.com
```

httpd.conf :

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted

</Directory>
```

Comment: mysite folder is empty?

Comment: Have you checked your directory permissions to ensure that apache has (at least) read access to the htdocs directory? If Apache is installed as a service (i.e. it will start with windows), then it will run as the System user.

Comment: @Metalik - not checked, but default it goes to xampp dashboard. its in htdocs only, so htdocs are accessible right?

Comment: Please let me know how to check the apache read access for htdocs.

Comment: try to change document root on virtual host https://valuebound.com/resources/blog/how-to-setup-virtual-host-windows-7-xampp-server

Comment: @Metalik - updated all the above but same issue. it reads .htaccess files of mysite but goes to xampp dashboard, then edited document root in httpd.conf, then getting same issue. [question updated]

Comment: @Metalik - from second url what can i update ?

Comment: second is wrong i deleted. ip indicated on error image is diffrent from 121.22.90.22 ip why?

Comment: @Metalik - image has the correct Ip. did not check vhost with ip still.

Comment: @MichaelThompson - May i know your suggestion for updated one.

Comment: @MichaelThompson - I think same, may have apche file read write permission issue, while installing apache got warning message.

Comment: @Metalik - followed the link but same issue.

Comment: I see you have managed to come to some resolution, however, to fix the directory read issue, you first need to know the username of the user running the process. It may be your username, it may be system. You're looking for the process called httpd.exe in task manager as per the following: https://superuser.com/a/893375/705993. Then, you need to allow that user the correct read and write permissions (on a dev server, I would just allow full control but not on a live server) as per the following (replacing "everyone" with the user who runs apache : https://serverfault.com/a/157688

Answer (score 0):

I have found that these 403 errors are (almost) always Apache configuration errors. Unfortunately there is not a lot of diagnostics in the logs for this.

Try this in your httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName example.local
      DocumentRoot "C:\Users\shipl\htdocs\example"
      <Directory "C:\Users\shipl\htdocs\example">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
      </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Your hosts then would have:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       example.local
```

Note that 'example.local' and '\htdocs\example' must be consistent in all the references.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is some improvement now, only specific directory gives same error,  created new folder in htdocs and tested with `phpinfo()` running fine.

Comment: What will be the issue in my old running directory?, it has index.php as well.

Comment: I am trying with IP address but project folder name is different. but its running fine for my first comment.

Comment: getting issue while add .htcdess to root directory. `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`

Comment: Glad it is working in a new folder. The issue with the old folder must be something else (given same Apache configuration.

Note that this is a configuration for HTTP, not HTTPS, which is another matter requiring different / additional configuration. You might want to raise a new question describing that issue.